# Is there a way to re-use the values stored in a locally scoped variable elsewhere in the global scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I created this function to retrieve local times from Edmonton. It refreshes every second to update a clock I have on an html page.

I'd like to use the value stored in the variables edmontonTodayTime and edmontonYesterdayTime in other functions, but because they're locally scoped I can't extract them.

I want to use these variables to filter through another dataset to only show results from the last 24 hours.

Is there a workaround for this? Many thanks.

```js
const retrieveTime = () => {
  const currentTime = new Date();
  const yesterdayTime = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1));

  //General function to convert local times to Edmonton time
  const convertTime = (time) => {
    const convertedTime = time.toLocaleString('en-CA', {timeZone: "America/Edmonton", year:"numeric", month:"short", day:"numeric", hr12:true, hour: "numeric", minute:"2-digit", second: "2-digit"});
    return convertedTime;
  }

  //Converted current and yesterday times in Edmonton time
  const edmontonTodayTime = convertTime(currentTime);
  $(".currentTime").text(`Current time: ${edmontonTodayTime}`);
  const edmontonYesterdayTime = convertTime(yesterdayTime);
  $(".latestDisruptions").text(`Disruptions announced in the last 24 hours (since ${edmontonYesterdayTime})`);

}
setInterval(retrieveTime, 1000);
```

Comment: You could make “retrieveTime” do what it says instead of also doing other things with the retrieved times.

Comment: Make them global variables instead of local variables.

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that the regularly updated current time can be applied elsewhere, with it automatically updating itself dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Make them global variables instead of local constants.

```js
let edmontonTodayTime;
let edmontonYesterdayTime;

const retrieveTime = () => {
  const currentTime = new Date();
  const yesterdayTime = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1));

  //General function to convert local times to Edmonton time
  const convertTime = (time) => {
    const convertedTime = time.toLocaleString('en-CA', {timeZone: "America/Edmonton", year:"numeric", month:"short", day:"numeric", hr12:true, hour: "numeric", minute:"2-digit", second: "2-digit"});
    return convertedTime;
  }

  //Converted current and yesterday times in Edmonton time
  edmontonTodayTime = convertTime(currentTime);
  $(".currentTime").text(`Current time: ${edmontonTodayTime}`);
  edmontonYesterdayTime = convertTime(yesterdayTime);
  $(".latestDisruptions").text(`Disruptions announced in the last 24 hours (since ${edmontonYesterdayTime})`);

}
setInterval(retrieveTime, 1000);
setTimeout(() => console.log(edmontonTodayTime), 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a way I could actually extract the time value from edmontonTodayTime and apply it elsewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by "extract the time value"? You could save the Date objects in the global variables instead of the converted times.

Comment: When I console.log edmontonTodayTime in the global scope it comes back as undefined. I want to be able to use the actual date stored in the locally scoped variable elsewhere.

Comment: Did you wait at least 1 second before logging it?

Comment: "Demonton Today" is _the_ #1 morning infotainment product in Hell.

Comment: Yes it comes back as undefined.

Comment: I've updated my snippet to show that it works. I use `setTimeout()` to print it 2 seconds later.

Comment: That worked! Thanks Barmar! So when passing this variable into other functions from the global scope, I'll have to set a slower interval too?